# JavaScript event parameter in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, events

I have this code:

```js
function buttonHighlight(event, img, name) {
    if (img === null) {
        img = event.target;
    }
    img.src = "img/" + name + "_on.png";
    img.style.cursor = "pointer";
}

function buttonLostHighlight(event, img, name) {
    if (img === null) {
        img = event.target;
    }
    img.src = "img/" + name + "_off.png";
    img.style.cursor = "auto";
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" form="login_form" id="log_window_b" class="fake_button" onclick="loginHandler()"> 
  <img src="img/send_off.png" alt="invia" width="55" height="15" onmouseover="buttonHighlight(event, null, 'send')" onmouseout="buttonLostHighlight(event, null, 'send')"> 
</button>
```

If I try this without the event parameter in the js function and in the html event attribute, it works fine in Chrome, but not in Firefox. But if i use this code in Firefox it doesn't work, it only works if "event" is the only attribute in the function, but I also need the other attributes!

Answer (score -1):

Is this an absolute requirement to achieve this in pure Javascript ?

Seeing your code, this could easily be done in CSS.

Comment: Yes, i know i can do this in CSS, but the real problem for me is understanding the reason why this doesn't work because i use the event object many times in my page.